# HTTP 500 Error from WP-Includes

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-500

I'm receiving an HTTP 500 error that was brought to my attention via Google search console. It appears that all of these 93 errors are originating from my wp-includes folder. Since none of these pages/files are intended to be viewable to users on my site, I am wondering why they are appearing as errors? What can I do to fix these?

Additionally, one thing I noticed is the dates that google search console found these errors seem to coincide with when I installed an ssl certificate on my site. I am not entirely sure if there is a possible correlation.

[image]

Comment: The 500 error are generate by backend side. Go to the, if use linux, `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log` in this logs you will see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I too keep getting these errors from time to time especially when I change the  theme or plugin. The simplest way to get rid of these errors is to mark them as "fixed" and wait for the next crawl. They usually become zero on the next crawl, but anytime if I make changes in my theme or plugins, they again start appearing. So I guess it is related to the deletion or installation of themes and plugins.